# How to locate compiler for mex in matlab?

Tags: windows, matlab, windows-10, mex

I want to run c code from Matlab. So i started to google and saw that using [mex](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/standalone-example.html), i can achieve it. But i got problem to run mex in matlab. Here's what i did:

**1.** At first i ran **mex -setup** in matlab command window. 
 **2.** Then i got the below response.

> Please choose your compiler for building MEX-files:
>  
>         Would you like mex to locate installed compilers [y]/n?

**3.** I wrote `y` and got below response

> No supported SDK or compiler was found on this computer.  For a list
>   of supported compilers, see
>   http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2013a/win64.html

**4.** I went to the link and downloaded the sdk and installed it in my **windows 10**. But while installing i got some problem but continued.
[image]
 **5.** Again repeated the whole process and wrote `y` but got same message as above.
 **6.** Then i tried by writing `n` and saw all the list of my compilers.

> ```
> [1] Intel C++ 13.0 (with Microsoft Software Development Kit (SDK) linker) 
> [2] Intel C++ 13.0 (with Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 linker) 
> [3] Intel C++ 13.0 (with Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 linker) 
> [4] Intel C++ 12.0 (with Microsoft Software Development Kit (SDK) linker) 
> [5] Intel C++ 12.0 (with Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 linker) 
> [6] Intel C++ 12.0 (with Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 linker) 
> [7] Intel C++ 11.1 (with Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 linker) 
> [8] Intel Visual Fortran 13 (with Microsoft Software Development Kit (SDK) linker) 
> [9] Intel Visual Fortran 13.0 (with Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 linker) 
> [10] Intel Visual Fortran 13.0 (with Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 linker) 
> [11] Intel Visual Fortran 12 (with Microsoft Software Development Kit (SDK) linker) 
> [12] Intel Visual Fortran 12.0 (with Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 linker) 
> [13] Intel Visual Fortran 12.0 (with Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Shell linker)
> [14] Intel Visual Fortran 12.0 (with Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 linker) 
> [15] Intel Visual Fortran 11.1 (with Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 linker) 
> [16] Intel Visual Fortran 11.1 (with Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Shell linker) 
> [17] Microsoft Software Development Kit (SDK) 7.1
> [18] Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 SP1 
> [19] Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 
> [20] Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 
> [21] Microsoft Visual C++ 2012
> ```

**7.** The number **17** is my installed sdk. so i got a response after selecting 17.

> Warning: The default location for Microsoft Software Development Kit
>   (SDK) compiler is: 
>            "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0" 
>            but either that directory does not exist or the configuration 
>            is invalid.

**8.** I have uninstalled visual studio from my computer and that directory remained 
 **Is there any easy way to run c file from matlab or how to install compiler for mex file ??**

**EDIT: Now what i found is Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) for Windows 10 from this [link](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk) and downloading it. I don't know that it will work or not??**

Comment: It's not clear from your question whether you want to call a dll (for instance) that is already compiled, or whether you want to compile a mex file. Which is it?  Also, does the directory that the error in step 7 reference exist?  And if not, where do you have the SDK installed?

Comment: yes that directory is present and but i uninstalled visual studio long ago.. And i want to compile a c file which is present in mex directory  and want to use that c file from a matlab file. I started looking for it when i saw that i couldn't compile that c file in matlab

Comment: Here's a link to [The MathWorks installation info for the SDK](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101105-how-do-i-install-microsoft-windows-sdk-7-1).  Note that you need that SDK even though it says windows 7.

Comment: yeah i installed the sdk by following this link.

Comment: And get error like this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1de7c9b4-1feb-4c98-b426-f7f02cbafa99/windows-sdk-71-on-windows-10 and now i am trying to do the second answer of this post and hoping for if can get any easy solution

Comment: There might be some useful info for you here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/95039-why-does-the-sdk-7-1-installation-fail-with-an-installation-failed-message-on-my-windows-system

Comment: Consider using [loadlibrary](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/loadlibrary.html) instead of mex.

Answer (score 1):

I can not remember how many times that I close with striking MEX files. The following way is time-consuming but effective.

1. Uninstall Visual Studios and SDKs from your computer.
2. Find a supported version of Visual Studio from ‘https://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers.html’
3. Install C++ and related libraries in this Visual Studios with default directory. Do not try to choose libraries by yourself.
4. Run ‘mex -setup’, and let it find the compiler.

The entire process will use up a whole morning with good luck.